# select row under condition of points distance

Tags: python, pandas, select, error-handling, distance

I have two data set crime and camera.(first pic is crime- Lon is Longitude , Lat is Latitude; second is camera- X is Longitude , Y is Latitude)

My purpose is select all the crimes whose distance are smaller than 200 feet within camera 89('OBJECTID'=89). In sql, it should be like

```
select*
from crime
where "distance with camera89" < 200feet
```

[image: crime data]
[image: camera data]

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import vincenty

crime = pd.read_csv('/Users/xccxken/Desktop/crime.csv',low_memory=False)
camera = pd.read_csv('/Users/xccxken/Desktop/camera.csv')

def xycamera(id):
    row=camera[camera['OBJECTID'] == id]
    x = row[['X']]
    y = row[['Y']]
    return x,y

print (xycamera(89))

c200 = crime[vincenty((crime['Lon'],crime['Lat']),xycamera(89)).feet>200]
```

I have a ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). in 
c200=crime[vincenty((crime['Lon'],crime['Lat']),xycamera(89)).feet>200]

I hope some one can tell me how to fix it.

And it would be better if there's a better method to achieve my goal. Thanks!

Here is a example of how to use vincenty()
and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy if you need

```
>>> from geopy.distance import vincenty
>>> newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
>>> cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
>>> print(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
538.3904451566326
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `vincenty()` expects your coordinates (tuples or whatnot), but for sure you are missing an opening parenthesis on your last line. (or you have an extra closing one). Based on your example, probably the parenthesis after `.feet` is the extra one

Try this one:

```
cameraCoords = xycamera(89)
vincenty((11,11),(12,12)).feet
crime[vincenty((crime['Lon'],crime['Lat']),cameraCoords ).feet>200]
```

run this one, paste your whole code and paste here the WHOLE traceback

Comment: thanks. i have fixed the parenthesis problem like you said. it works. but there's a new error now. hope you can help me if you have time

Comment: What's the new error? what's the output of xycamera(89)?

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: (            X
87 -77.628824,            Y
87  43.13503) result like this

Comment: (            X
87 -77.628824,            Y
87  43.13503)output of xycamera(89)  like this

Comment: use row['X'].values[0] insted of row[['X']], output of the xcamera should be (-77, 87), not (X -77, Y 87)

Comment: thanks. sorry i have tried this, but it still has the same error

Comment: you are doing too much in in line, that's why it's hard to trace down the error.